# How to safely flatten svn repository structure

Tags: svn, migration, admin

I inherited a svn repository with the following structure:

```
Repo
 |-WG1
   |--ProjectA
   |--ProjectB
 |-WG2
  |--ProjectC
```

Where WGx where work groups.

As our structure has been flattened so would I also like to flatten the svn structure to simply:

```
RepoCloud
 |-ProjectA
 |-ProjectB
 |-ProjectC
```

I know I can do this moving directories, BUT, I'm migrating the svn to a cloud hosted repository and I had bad experiences in the path when exporting/importing repositories after moving stuff around.

It's safe to do this change before migrating or better to migrate and the flatten the new repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it before or after, and it'll be equally safe. But it'll be a pain for end users regardless.

- `svn switch` changes your WC to point at a different path in the same repository.
- `svn relocate` (or `svn switch --relocate` in older releases) changes your WC to point at the same path in a different repository.

There isn't a way to change both the repository *and* the path that your WC points at. So you're going to end up having to check out new WCs either way.